# Webpack и jQuery плагины

Tags: jquery, webpack, inputmask

Моя задача простая, надо подключить JQuey, JqueryInputmask и собственно мой скрипт.

*app.js*

```
window.$ = require('jquery');
window.Inputmask = require('inputmask');

require('./myscript');
```

*myscript.js*

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    Inputmask({mask: '999-999-99-99'}).mask('#phone');
});
```

И это работает, но мне хотелось бы вместо `Inputmask({mask: '999-999-99-99'}).mask('#phone');` использовать классическую запись `$('#phone').inputmask('999-999-99-99');`

Возможно ли такое сделать или лучше просто использовать тэг `<script>` для подключения `jQuery` и плагинов?

Не знаю нужна ли эта информация но используется `Webpack 4`, `Laravel 5.7`, `Laravel Mix`

Comment: А что значит "или лучше использовать тег..." А как вы щас подключили jQuery?

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц сейчас подключил `window.$ = require('jquery');`, дело в том что сам jQuery работает, я не могу подключить плагины не inpumask, не tooltip, ничего вообще не работает.  выдает ошибку $(...).inpumask is not a function

Comment: Эта строка не обеспечивает подключения jQuery. Зайдите через инспектор и убедитесь что у вас правильно подключен jQuery и версия его полная

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц jQuery подключился, и подключился Inputmask но вот так работает `Inputmask({mask: '999-999-99-99'}).mask('#phone');` , а вот так нет `$('#phone').inputmask('999-999-99-99');`

Comment: Посмотрите [этот](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43130272/jquery-input-mask-for-phone-number) вопрос

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц спасибо конечно за ваши старания но суть вопроса в другом. Я знаю как работает inputmask. Вопрос в том как подключать jQuery плагины именно через Webpack